# PHP array object converting

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of object

```
([date]=>2012-01-09, [count]=>5),
([date]=>2012-01-11, [count]=>7),
([date]=>2012-01-12, [count]=>5)
```

What is the best way to convert the array to array object or array

```
([date]=>2012-01-08, [count]=>0),
([date]=>2012-01-09, [count]=>5),
([date]=>2012-01-10, [count]=>0),
([date]=>2012-01-11, [count]=>7),
([date]=>2012-01-12, [count]=>5),
([date]=>2012-01-13, [count]=>0),
([date]=>2012-01-14, [count]=>0)
```

assume given the startdate 2012-01-08 and enddate 2012-01-14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. generate date from startdate to enddate
2. create an empty associative array to store your datewise data.
3. traverse all the dates generated in #1 one by one
4. if the count for current date exists in initial array, store that in array created in #2, else store count as 0, with array key being `(string) $currentDate`
5. the array of step#2 will now have the required data.

Convert this into PHP code :)

Answer (score 0):

I won't write the code for you, but I'll provide you the algorithm

```
$compArray = new array();

loop from startdate to enddate as date
{
    if (in_array(date, yourarray))
        copy the entry from yourarray to compArray
    else
        enter date into compArray with a count of 0
}
```